# Verifying item existence in list gives wrong result

Tags: class, exception, arraylist, collections, types

I am having difficulty in displaying the expected output to the function "bookShow"

List showlist = is the list of Shows, Show timing and the number of seats                                available for every show

String showName = is the showName the user has entered

String show_time  = is the showTimethe user has entered

int noOfSeats= is the number of seats the user has entered

i want the function to display "UnknownShowException" if the showName entered by the user doesnt belong to the list.

but no matter what i type as the showName, it gives me the Exception. even if the showName is present in the List,it still gives me the exception.

```
public void bookShow(List<Show> showList, String showName,  String show_time, int noOfSeats)
        throws SeatsNotAvailableException, UnknownShowException, InvaildSeatNumberException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        List<Show> list=showList;
        Iterator<Show> itr= list.iterator();
        try{
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            if(noOfSeats<0){
                throw new InvaildSeatNumberException();
            }
         if(noOfSeats>itr.next().getSeatsAvailable()){
                throw new SeatsNotAvailableException();
            }

            if(!(list.contains(showName))){
                throw new UnknownShowException();
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("" + e);
    }
}   
  }
```

Please tell me where i am going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

ShowName is a string and Showlist is a List of Show Object, So when you search a specific string in the list of shows you get none because no show object is equal to your string. you'll have to match your string to the show name property in your show object.
So if Show Object Has Property "Name" the following will work

```
public void bookShow(List<Show> showList, String showName,  String show_time, int noOfSeats)
        throws SeatsNotAvailableException, UnknownShowException, InvaildSeatNumberException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        List<Show> list=showList;
        Iterator<Show> itr= list.iterator();
        try{
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            if(noOfSeats<0){
                throw new InvaildSeatNumberException();
            }
         if(noOfSeats>itr.next().getSeatsAvailable()){
                throw new SeatsNotAvailableException();
            }

            if(!(list.Any(x=>x.Name == showName))){
                throw new UnknownShowException();
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("" + e);
    }
}   
  }
```